# Database for Full Text Search and 200M+ Records

Tags: mysql, mongodb, elasticsearch, database

Iam about to create a huge database with at least 200 Million entries.
The database needs to be searchable using full text and should be fast.

My database gets data from many different datasources and i need to import the new or updated data regularly.

Is it a good idea to store all my data in a relational database like mysql and then create a nosql document database (e.g. mongodb or elasticsearch) just for the purpose of searching or does that not provide any benefit in terms of 
reliability and the prevention of redundant information?

Comment: With elasticsearch you can benefit from reliability and horizontal scalability, i.e. speed at a cost, but generally speaking questions to recommend software are off-topic.

Comment: Thx but the question is not about the "correct" software but more about if there is any benefit in having the same data in a relational database.

Comment: If you need **only** text search you are good with ES alone. If you need anything else, e.g. transactions, consistency, etc. I'd suggest to use a SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that keeping primary records in a SQL database and duplicating them to a noSQL database is a very common approach.

ElasticSearch has an ongoing status page about their [resiliency](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/resiliency/current/index.html). Even in the newest version, ElasticSearch can loose data in [a number of different situations](https://aphyr.com/posts/323-jepsen-elasticsearch-1-5-0). A major change in the structure of an ElasticSearch index (such as adding analyzers) requires that you [re-index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) all of the documents. This process is safer if you have another source for the documents. At the end of the day, ElasticSearch isn't designed to consistently store documents - I would only ever choose to use ElasticSearch as the primary store in situations where occasional data loss isn't a disaster.

Unlike ElasticSearch, MongoDB is designed to be [resilient](https://jepsen.io/analyses/mongodb-3-4-0-rc3). You should be able to safely store documents in MongoDB. I've found trying to do full text searches in MongoDB can be a little painful, at least compared to ElasticSearch. In my opinion, for text search, the only advantage MongoDB has over MySQL's [FULLTEXT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html) is that it is distributed.

We are running ElasticSearch and MySQL right now - and the benefits greatly outweigh the hassles of extra infrastructure and dealing with replication between the two. We had previously attempted to use a noSQL solution as the primary datastore, with disastrous results. Running a ES in conjunction with a MySQL gets you the best of both worlds - consistency & safety of data in SQL, with the scalable, effective full text search in ES.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how applicable to your situation this is, but [Evan Weaver compared a few of the common Rails search options (Sphinx, Ferret and Solr)](https://blog.evanweaver.com/2008/03/17/rails-search-benchmarks/), running some benchmarks.